# use of setOrientation method on a LinearList object

Tags: android, setorientation

The setOrientation method of LinearLayout will not accept the argument VERTICAL, contrary to the following from the android reference

public void setOrientation (int orientation)
Since: API Level 1
Should the layout be a column or a row.
Related XML Attributes
    * android:orientation
Parameters
orientation     Pass HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL. Default value is HORIZONTAL.

I have tried, unsuccessfully, using import android.widget.LinearLayout.*

By hacking around I was able to find that 1 is vertical, which works fine, but this is a bug that should be fixed.

Answer (score 44):

```
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 4):

> The setOrientation method of LinearLayout will not accept the argument VERTICAL

Yes, it does. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Containers/Linear) that has worked for about three years, certainly on every shipping version of Android.

> By hacking around I was able to find that 1 is vertical, which works fine, but this is a bug that should be fixed.

The bug is in your code.